# The "default_icon: {}" isn't working in my manifest.json

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

The manifest.json keeps giving me this error when I run it.  All the image files with the corresponding names are in the folder.

Failed to load extension
File ~\Downloads\MyExtension

```
Error Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 10, column: 3, Syntax error.
{
  "name": "Calculator Extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple calculator to help you in life!",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "author": "Mippy",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Calculator"
        "default_icon": {
        "16": "favicon16.png",
        "32": "favicon32.png"
    }
  }
  "icons": {
      "16": "favicon16.png",
      "32": "favicon32.png",
      "48": "icon48.png",
      "128": "icon128.png"
  }
}
```

Also, the error isn't the spacing, I already tried that.

I tried:

1. Making sure the image names matched with the manifest and were in the folder.
2. Rearranging the code

I was expecting that the extension would have the images, however it resulted in the error above.

Comment: you missed a comma sign after line `"default_title": "Calculator"`

Comment: To add to @zmii there is also a comma missing after closing bracket of the "action" field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed a comma sign after line "default_title": "Calculator" and also after end of `"actions"` object. Try this:

```
{
  "name": "Calculator Extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple calculator to help you in life!",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "author": "Mippy",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Calculator",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "favicon16.png",
      "32": "favicon32.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "favicon16.png",
    "32": "favicon32.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  }
}
```

there are online JSON validators you can use to validate issues with your JSON, like this one - https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/